# Crear un contador "añadir o disminuir" en Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy creando una app con una estructura de compras donde la lista de productos se detallan en un recycler view..
quiero implementar un "contador de productos"
tengo estructurado el siguiente adaptador donde lo "visual" lo carga sin problemas:

```
public class UsuariosImagenAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuariosImagenAdapter.UsuariosHolder> implements 
View.OnClickListener {


List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
static final int TYPE_CELL = 1;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        default:
            return TYPE_CELL;
    }
}
public UsuariosImagenAdapter(List<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
    this.listaUsuarios = listaUsuarios;
}


@Override
public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



    View view = null;



    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_HEADER: {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_big, parent, false);
            return new UsuariosHolder(view) {
            }
                    ;
        }
        case TYPE_CELL: {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_small, parent, false);

            return new UsuariosHolder(view) {
            }
                    ;
        }
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            break;
        case TYPE_CELL:

            holder.txtDocumento.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getDocumento().toString());
            holder.txtNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getNombre().toString());
            holder.txtProfesion.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getProfesion().toString());
            holder.btMas.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.btMenos.setOnClickListener(this);

                            if (listaUsuarios.get(position).getImagen() != null) {
                holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(listaUsuarios.get(position).getImagen());
            } else {
                holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.iconousuario);
            }



    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaUsuarios.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Selector que actuará en función al botón que llame al evento.
    switch (view.getId()) {
        // En el caso de que lo llame el botón más.
        case R.id.botonmas:


            break;
        // En el caso de que lo llame el botón menos.
        case R.id.botonmenos:

            break;

    }



}

public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView txtDocumento,txtNombre,txtProfesion;
    ImageView imagen;
    ImageView btMas, btMenos;



    public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtDocumento= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDocumento);
        txtNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
        txtProfesion= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idProfesion);
        imagen=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        tvNumTazas = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.numeroitem);
        // declaro las imagenes clieckeables pero no se como trabajarlos
        //btMas = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonmas);
        //btMenos = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonmenos);

    }
}
}
```

**Lo que necesito hacer es crear un contador que se actualice conforme aumenta o disminuya, limitando su valor min. a 0 para cada producto y estaría en cada "item" de mi recycler asi:**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría implementar ese contador para después trabajar con esos datos y realizar operaciones matematicas para realizar un "carrito de compras"
De antemano agradezco su ayuda